# C++ - Recover Template or cast to Template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Consider the following code listing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Interface { };

template<typename T>
class Class : public Interface { };

template<typename T>
Interface *producer() {
    std::cout << "produced " << typeid(T).name();
    return new Class<T>();
}

template<typename T>
void consumer(Class<T> *class_value) {
    std::cout << "consumed " << typeid(T).name();
}

void mediator(Interface *value) {
    /* The magic happens here */
    consumer(class_value);
}

int main() {
    Interface *value = producer<int>();
    mediator(value);
}
```

Is there any possible way to call the 'consumer' template function from the 'mediator' function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The direct answer**

It looks like the code you post has been written to illicit the use of a cast and adding a suitable case seems the direct answer.

```
void mediator(Interface *value) {
    /* The magic happens here */
    Class<int> *class_value(static_cast<Class<int> *>(value));
    consumer(class_value);
}
```

In this case since it's known that only the `int` version will arrive we can use a `static_cast`.

**Doesn't scale**

However this approach does not scale well if `Class` is specialized for more types.

For example to have `mediator` handle `float` as well you would need to try each of the types:

```
void mediator(Interface *value) {
    /* The magic happens here */

    {
        Class<int> *class_value(dynamic_cast<Class<int> *>(value));
        if(class_value) {
            consumer(class_value);
            return;
        }
    }

    {
        Class<float> *class_value(dynamic_cast<Class<float> *>(value));
        if(class_value) {
            consumer(class_value);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Double dispatch**

Changing the design as Kerrek SB suggests to use [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) gives a much cleaner and scalable solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your design a little, you could make the derived class do the work:

```
class Interface
{
    virtual void consume() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {}
};

void mediator(Interface * value)
{
    value->consume();
}

template <typename T>
void consumer(Class<T> * class_value)
{
    std::cout << "consumed " << typeid(T).name();
}

template <typename T> class Class : public Interface
{
    virtual void consume() override
    { 
        consumer<Class>(this);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
consumer(dynamic_cast<producer<int>&>(value));
```